# match_df from matchmaker does not work on all columns?

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning

I am cleaning string data using the `matchmaker` package. I've created my dictionary with `from`,  `to`, and `col` columns to define the uncleaned terms, cleaned terms, and column names where the uncleaned terms in the file can be found.

The original data look something like this

```
ID <- 1:5
var1 <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", NA)
var2 <- c("ccc", "ddd", NA, NA,"aaa")
var3 <- c(NA, NA, "bbb", NA, "aaa")

df <- data.frame(ID, var1, var2, var3)
```

Here is what the dictionary like

```
from <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", 
          "ccc", "ddd", "aaa", 
          "bbb", "aaa")
to <- c("Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc", "Ddd", 
        "Ccc", "Ddd", "Aaa", 
        "Bbb", "Aaa")
col <- c("var1", "var1", "var1", "var1", 
         "var2", "var2", "var2", 
         "var3", "var3")

dictionary <- data.frame(from, to, col)
```

I used the following code:

```
library(matchmaker)
match_df(df, dictionary = dictionary, 
              from = "from", 
              to = "to", 
              by = "col")
```

Here is the result I expected:

```
  ID var1 var2 var3
1  1  Aaa  Ccc <NA>
2  2  Bbb  Ddd <NA>
3  3  Ccc <NA>  Bbb
4  4  Ddd <NA> <NA>
5  5 <NA>  Aaa  Aaa
```

Here is the result I got

```
  ID var1 var2 var3
1  1  aaa  Ccc <NA>
2  2  bbb  Ddd <NA>
3  3  ccc <NA>  Bbb
4  4  ddd <NA> <NA>
5  5 <NA>  Aaa  Aaa
```

The code works for this example, but with real dataset I have it did not. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Friede. Too bad it still doesn't work. 

Also point of clarification, the example returns the expected result to me as well. It was when I applied the code to my real dataset that the problem showed up.

Comment: Try to provide an example that does not work. It is hard to help you if we can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, been busy with exams. I cannot reproduce the error with made up data. I do found that if I specify `warn = TRUE` in the `match_df` command, I would get the follwing error message for the column which the code doesn't work 

`1. NA Each element of '...' must be a named string.` 

@friede @JosepPueyo, do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who comes across this thread looking for a solution for a similar issue that results in the following message:

> 1. NA Each element of '...' must be a named string.

check if your dictionary has any "NA" or blank in it. Once you remove the line with NA, your `match_df()` command should work for all columns.